# See "Unfortunately, Google play service has stopped" when starting app from ARC Welder

Tags: google-chrome-arc

My app have some google play services integrated. The metadata is

```
{"usePlayServices":["gcm","maps"]}
```

When I start the app inside ARC Welder (on Chrome OS 46.0.2490.71). Sometimes I see the error

> "Unfortunately, Google play service has stopped"

And the app crashes.

In the log console, I see the error message

> "Authentication error Error: The user is not signed in."

The crash usually happens the 1st time when I load the apk in ARC Welder and test it. In the subsequent launches (w/o config changes in Welder), the app starts without crash. Although I still see the same auth error in the log. So I am not sure if the auth error is related to the crash.

Any idea?